# comet programming using JS or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, web, comet

I am new to comet programming.
I need to get data from the server whenever there is any update, as well as other notifications from the clients.

I need to implement comet programming using JS or PHP. I want to know whether it will have performance issues and scalability. I would like to get some information that will help me achieve this.

Comment: There's google to answer this question for you... also: Comet can't be done PHP-only, as it requires continuous client <=> server communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comet programming you can use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) you can also use  [meteor](http://meteor.com/).
Server side javascript can run using node.js and meteor runs in Node.js container on server-side.